# How to work with js arrays, finding and grouping items?

Tags: javascript, sorting, filter, grouping

Googled around a fair bit but couldn't wrap my head around how to deal with this problem.

I have/plan a list of items.

```
var list1 = [
  [141,'AAA', 'A Group'],
  [262,'BBB', 'B Group'],
  [345,'CCC', 'B Group'],
  [136,'DDD'],
  [095,'EEE', 'A Group'],
  [175,'FFF'], and so on...
];
```

My goal is to print these items.
Groups first, in alphabetical. Groupless after that.

All items in alphabetical.

Final result would be something like:

```
<div>

<h2>A Group</h2>
<ul class="group">
    <li>
        <img src="/141">
        <h3>AAA</h3>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="/095">
        <h3>EEE</h3>
    </li>
</ul>

<h2>B Group</h2>
<ul class="group">
    <li>
        <img src="/262">
        <h3>BBB</h3>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="/345">
        <h3>CCC</h3>
    </li>
</ul>

<h2>No group</h2>
<ul class="non-group">
    <li>
        <img src="/136">
        <h3>DDD</h3>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="/175">
        <h3>FFF</h3>
    </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

---

**Any thoughts on how to tackle this?**

---

Found this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7596924/543365

Fairly close to what I could use. Couldn't manage to bend it to my use though.

Comment: @tracevipin based on his referred link I think he was trying to figure something out working with `shift` and `unshift`. Off course for a multi-dimensional array that would result in some messy stack of checks to get it all working.

Comment: Please state exactly what kind of sorting you want. You want sorting inside each group. Or sorting the groups themselves by their name..

Comment: I would like the groups in A-Z. The items, grouped or not, A-Z.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking into **underscorejs**, but, if you wish to use pure javascript:

1.) Sort the list so the items with a group come first.

```
var i = 0,
    group_arr = [];
for (i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
    if (list1[i][2] !== undefined) {
        group_arr.append(list1.splice(i, 1)[0]);
    }
}
```

2.) Now all the items with a group are in `group_arr` and the ones without are in `list1`. We need to now sort `group_arr` so it is in alphabetical order by group:

```
group_arr.sort(function (item1, item2) {
    return (item1[2] > item2[2]) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Note that we can sort `group_arr` based on any arbitrary condition. If you would like to sort alphabetically by the second entry, just index that in the comparator function passed into `Array.prototype.sort`.

3.) Now the items in `group_arr` are in alphabetical order by group and contain items that have a group. Items in `list 1` have no group and are not sorted. You can now iterate through each of these arrays, create your DOM elements and then insert them.

Comment: Pure JS is not a requirement :)

Answer (score 0):

Vinay's answer is great. Something like this should work too:

```
var list1 = [
    [141,'AAA', 'A Group'],
    [262,'BBB', 'B Group'],
    [345,'CCC', 'B Group'],
    [136,'DDD'],
    [095,'EEE', 'A Group'],
    [175,'FFF']
];

var list1_new = list1.sort(function(a, b){
    if (a[2] == b[2]) {
        return 0; // Do nothing
    }

    if (a[2] > b[2]) {
        return 1; // Put a AFTER b
    }

    if (a[2] < b[2]) {
        return -1; // Put a BEFORE b
    }
});

console.log(list1_new);
```

You could re-run the `sort()` function to handle the other values too after the index `2` is checked (Groups), to sort them all out after one and another.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I agree, good answer by Vinay, I would have suggested underscore as well and made you a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybuBE/).

```
var groups = _.filter(list1,function(entry){
    return entry.length == 3;
});

var groupsSorted = _.sortBy(groups,function(entry){
    return entry[2] + entry[1]; //sort by group name and second element
});
```

Comment: The nice thing about what `sort()` comparison does (based on your first check if the length is equal to 3), is that `undefined == undefined`, making it no real worry using `a[2] == b[2]` to see if they both don't have a 3rd index key. Good answer tho, love it! :)

Comment: That's quite neat, and would just need grouping.