# change table details group when text box is clicked

Tags: sorting, reporting-services

Is there a way to dynamically change the table details grouping when a text box is clicked?

For example, I have a "Date" labelled textbox. When I clicked the Date textbox, the table will group by Date

**Original Layout**

```
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4
-Primary Colors
|  Blue   |   Data  |  Data   |   Data 
|  Red    |   Data  |  Data   |   Data
|  Yellow |   Data  |  Data   |   Data
-Secondary Colors
|  Green  |   Data  |  Data   |   Data 
|  Orange |   Data  |  Data   |   Data
|  Violet |   Data  |  Data   |   Data
```

After I click the interactive sort of Column1, the groupings will change to this:

```
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4
-Colors
|  Blue   |   Data  |  Data   |   Data 
|  Green  |   Data  |  Data   |   Data
|  Orange |   Data  |  Data   |   Data
|  Red    |   Data  |  Data   |   Data 
|  Violet |   Data  |  Data   |   Data
|  Yellow |   Data  |  Data   |   Data
```

Comment: Do you mean a dynamic array sorting ? This can be done in javascript. Some similar posts are existing like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596794/group-array-items-based-on-variable-javascript

Comment: nope, it is more of changing the groupings.